# Limit select count subquery work in 21.4.5.46 version but can not work in 21.10.2.15

Tags: clickhouse

Limit select count subquery work in 21.4.5.46 version but can not work in 21.10.2.15

Sql is

```
select * from mytable order by sid limit (select toInt64(count(cid)*0.01)　from mytable);
```

The sql can work very well in in 21.4.5.46 version but can not work in 21.10.2.15.

```
Exception is : [1002] ClickHouse exception, message: Code: 440. DB::Exception: Illegal type Nullable(Int32) of LIMIT expression, must be numeric type. (INVALID_LIMIT_EXPRESSION) (version 21.10.2.15 (official build))
```

How to reproduce

1 create table sql:

```
create table mytable(cid String,create_time String,sid String)engine = MergeTree PARTITION BY sid ORDER BY cid SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192;
```

2 execute sql

```
select * from mytable order by sid limit (select toInt64(count(cid)*0.01)　from mytable);
```

Answer (score 0):

### ClickHouse release v21.9, 2021-09-09

- Backward Incompatible Change

  - Now, scalar subquery always returns Nullable result if it's type can be Nullable. It is needed because in case of empty subquery it's result should be Null. Previously, it was possible to get error about incompatible types (type deduction does not execute scalar subquery, and it could use not-nullable type). Scalar subquery with empty result which can't be converted to Nullable (like Array or Tuple) now throws error. Fixes #25411. #26423 (Nikolai Kochetov).

### Now you should use

```sql
SELECT *
FROM mytable
ORDER BY sid ASC
LIMIT assumeNotNull((
    SELECT toUInt64(count(cid) * 0.01)
    FROM mytable
))

Query id: e3ab56af-96e4-4e01-812d-39af945d7878

Ok.

0 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.004 sec.
```